# Differential Transformation Method

Tags: packages

I am using the differential transformation method (DTM) to solve the differential equation.
Is there any Mathematica package for differential transformation method?

Comment: Could you provide a reference / link to more info about this method?

Comment: Zaid M. Odibat, Cyrille Bertelle, M.A. Aziz-Alaoui, Gérard H.E. Duchamp, A multi-step differential transform method and application to non-chaotic or chaotic systems, In Computers & Mathematics with Applications, Volume 59, Issue 4, 2010, Pages 1462-1472.

Comment: The article cited by the OP can be found [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00430504/document).  I am not aware of an existing package for this method, but it probably could be implemented without too much difficulty.

Comment: Can you provide this paper code for practice. I wanted to know about its programming.